# What is the distribution of X?

Tags: distributions, self-study

Let a random variable X have a t distribution with n degrees of freedom. What is the distribution of X^2?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far to try to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X \sim t_n$. By definition, we have

$X = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{U/n}}$

where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $U \sim \chi^2_n$, and $Z$ and $U$ are independent. Therefore,

$$X^2 = \frac{Z^2 / 1}{U/n}$$.

Notice that $Z^2$ and $U$ are still independent. Furthermore, $Z^2 \sim \chi^2_1$. $X^2$ is the ratio of two independent chi-squared random variables divided by their degrees of freedom. So, $X^2 \sim F_{1,n}$.